# PropertyAccessException from Hibernate during persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, glassfish, jpa-2.1

I have an Entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_T")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TEST_S", initialValue = 1)
public class TestEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TEST_S")
    private Long id;

    public TestEntity() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    //further getters, setters etc
}
```

Which works wonderful with Glassfish4.0 and the built-in EclipseLink. But when I instead use Hibernate (4.3.11) as the JPA provider, persisting an entity fails with the following Exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.eclipselink.bug.TestEntity.id
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.eclipselink.bug.TestEntity.id
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:521)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field foo.bar.TestEntity.id to foo.bar.TestEntity
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.getLong(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    ... 61 more
```

I've attempted changing (or omitting) the `GenerationStrategy` and changed the `id` type to `long` and even `int` to no avail. What can I do to make Hibernate persist my entity?

Comment: do you have a  "public long getId();" ?

Comment: @VinhNT yes. I omitted them to make the example shorter but I guess the comment in the code wasn't clear enough, so I've put the relevant methods back in.

Comment: What type is your id field in the database?

Comment: @Jens a `Number(19)` (using Oracle 12.1.0.1). The tables are generated by JPA/Hibernate.